# Django test returns 404 despite of correct URL

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am using this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/18/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-3.html#introduction) for learning Django Test. On running the following error:

```
➜  DjangoSimpleIsBetter python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F......
======================================================================
FAIL: test_board_topics_view_contains_link_back_to_homepage (boards.tests.BoardTopicsTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/X/Data/Development/PetProjects/DjangoSimpleIsBetter/boards/tests.py", line 47, in test_board_topics_view_contains_link_back_to_homepage
    self.assertContains(response, 'href="{0}"'.format(homepage_url))
  File "/Users/X/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 462, in assertContains
    response, text, status_code, msg_prefix, html)
  File "/Users/X/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 434, in _assert_contains
    " (expected %d)" % (response.status_code, status_code)
AssertionError: 404 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve content: Response code was 404 (expected 200)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.068s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Below is the Test code:

```
class BoardTopicsTests(TestCase):
    def test_board_topics_view_contains_link_back_to_homepage(self):
        board_topics_url = reverse('board_topics', kwargs={'id': 1})
        response = self.client.get(board_topics_url)
        homepage_url = reverse('home')
        self.assertContains(response, 'href="{0}"'.format(homepage_url))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from boards import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^boards/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.board_topics, name='board_topics')
```

Comment: I think we'll need the entire stacktrace and `urls.py`

Comment: Your database likely has no object with `pk=1`. Exactly where do you create one? Note that Django's tests run on a *separate* database to prevent the tests from interfering with the (production) data.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes, Sir you are right! I just checked that I had not included `setUp` in it.